# bootstrap-datepicker : how to close only when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jsp, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to make datepicker close only if click outside. 
To prevent closing before clicking outside, I delete hide function like this:

```
$('#datepicker').data('datepicker').hide = function () {};
```

But if I do this, it's not able to close datepicker.

How do I fix this?

Code below:

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" class="form-control" value='<%=selectDate%>' onchange="hide()">


<script>

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: false
    }); 
    $('#datepicker').data('datepicker').hide = function () {}; 

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

just add the class datetimepicker-input ej.

```
<input type="text" class=" datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker4" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker4" dir="auto" required=""  readonly >
```

when de jquery is

```
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
```

I found this page to explain the details https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" class="form-control" value='<%=selectDate%>' onchange="hide()">


<script>

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: false
    }); 
    $('#datepicker').data('datepicker').hide = function () {}; 

</script>
```

on this code, `onSelect` func didn't work and couldn't use `hide()` func
so changed this into by using

```
.on("changeDate", function (e) {
    $('.datepicker').show();  
}
```

it worked for me